# Storm fields grouping

Tags: apache-storm

I'm having the following situation:

- There is a number of bolts that calculate different values
- This values are sent to visualization bolt
- Visualization bolt opens a web socket and sends values to be visualized somehow

The thing is, visualization bolt is always the same, but it sends a message with a different header for each type of bolt that can be its input. For example:

- BoltSum calculates sum
- BoltDif calculates difference
- BoltMul calculates multiple
- All this bolts use VisualizationBolt for visualization
- There are 3 instances of VisualizationBolt in this case

My question is, should I create 3 independent instances, where each instance will have one thread, e.g.

```
builder.setBolt("forSum", new VisualizationBolt(),1).globalGrouping("bolt-sum");
builder.setBolt("forDif", new VisualizationBolt(),1).globalGrouping("bolt-dif");
builder.setBolt("forMul", new VisualizationBolt(),1).globalGrouping("bolt-mul");
```

Or should I do the following

```
builder.setBolt("forAll", new VisualizationBolt(),3)
.fieldsGrouping("forSum", new Fields("type"))
.fieldsGrouping("forDif", new Fields("type"))
.fieldsGrouping("forMul", new Fields("type"));
```

And emit type from each of the previous bolts, so they can be grouped on based on it?

What are the advantages?

Also, should I expect that each and every time bolt-sum will go to first visualization bolt, bolt-dif will go to second visualization bolt and bolt-mul will go to third visualization bolt? They won't be mixed?

I think that that should be the case, but it currently isn't in my implementation, so I'm not sure if it's a bug or I'm missing something?

Comment: Fields grouping is correctly explained here: http://nrecursions.blogspot.in/2016/09/understanding-fields-grouping-in-apache.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach using three instances is the correct approach. Using `fieldsGrouping` does **not** ensure, that "sum" values go to "Sum-Visualization-Bolt" and neither that sum/diff/mul values are distinct (ie, in different bolt instances).

The semantic of `fieldGrouping` is more relaxed: it only guarantees, that all tuples of the same type will be processed by a single bolt instance, ie, that it will never be the case, that two different bolt instances get the same type.

Comment: Oh, I see, so it is possible that sum and difference will go to one bolt? That's the kind of problem I was having, outputs from previous bolts got mixed, even though I did grouping by field.

Comment: Exactly. A single bolt instance can get multiple types (only a single type will not go to different instanced using `fieldsGrouping`)

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir, I get it now. I thought that distribution will be more "fair", since there are X bolts and X keys so that each of the bolts will get instances for one key, but now I understand that it is not such a case. It was a pleasure discussing with you through both of my questions. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use **Partial Key grouping** (`partialKeyGrouping`). On the [Storm documentation about stream groups](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.2.2/Concepts.html) says:

> Partial Key grouping: The stream is partitioned by the fields
>   specified in the grouping, like the Fields grouping, but are load
>   balanced between two downstream bolts, which provides better
>   utilization of resources when the incoming data is skewed. This paper
>   provides a good explanation of how it works and the advantages it
>   provides.

I implemented a simple topology using this grouping and the chart on Graphite server show a better load balance compared to `fieldsGrouping`. The full source code is [here](https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-storm/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sense/storm/topology/MqttSensorExpensiveShuffleTopology.java).

```
topologyBuilder.setBolt(MqttSensors.BOLT_SENSOR_TYPE.getValue(), new SensorAggregateValuesWindowBolt().withTumblingWindow(Duration.seconds(5)), 2)
        // .fieldsGrouping(MqttSensors.SPOUT_STATION_01.getValue(), new Fields(MqttSensors.FIELD_SENSOR_TYPE.getValue()))
        // .fieldsGrouping(MqttSensors.SPOUT_STATION_02.getValue(), new Fields(MqttSensors.FIELD_SENSOR_TYPE.getValue()))
        .partialKeyGrouping(MqttSensors.SPOUT_STATION_01.getValue(), new Fields(MqttSensors.FIELD_SENSOR_TYPE.getValue()))
        .partialKeyGrouping(MqttSensors.SPOUT_STATION_02.getValue(), new Fields(MqttSensors.FIELD_SENSOR_TYPE.getValue()))
        .setNumTasks(4) // This will create 4 Bolt instances 
        .addConfiguration(TagSite.SITE.getValue(), TagSite.EDGE.getValue())
        ;
```

[image]