# ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory what is the reason for this error

Tags: apache-storm

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:39) at kafka.utils.Logging$class.logger(Logging.scala:24) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.logger$lzycompute(SimpleConsumer.scala:35) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.logger(SimpleConsumer.scala:35) at kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:77) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.info(SimpleConsumer.scala:35) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:94) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:83) at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:149) at kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:79) at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:75) at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.getOffset(KafkaUtils.java:65) at org.apache.storm.kafka.PartitionManager.(PartitionManager.java:103) at org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.refresh(ZkCoordinator.java:98) at org.apache.storm.kafka.ZkCoordinator.getMyManagedPartitions(ZkCoordinator.java:69) at org.apache.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:129) at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__7990$fn__8005$fn__8036.invoke(executor.clj:648) at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:484) at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: May be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054294/kafkaspout-throws-noclassdeffounderror-for-log4j

Comment: Ya it is a duplicate but I saw those answers and I tried to solved it also but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: When I am submitting the topology that time it is not showing the error but when I am refreshing the Storm UI page then it is showing the error.                        Anyone has the proper POM.XML file for submitting the topology I am using Storm 1.0.2 version.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the dependencies to log4j, but then you will need to exclude them from storm to avoid the conflict expained in the link I put on the comment:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hey david It is not working still I have tried with the above dependency.