# Kafkameter NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jmeter, apache-kafka, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am looking to load test Kafka by sending dynamically generated messages to a Kafka consumer by way of the [jMeter extension](https://github.com/BrightTag/kafkameter), installed by the [jMeter plugin manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).

My Kafka is configured, set up and running perfectly. I followed [these instructions](http://www.technix.in/load-testing-apache-kafka-using-kafkameter/) to set up a Kafka test plan and run it, but every time I set one up and run it, I get this error in the log:

```
2017/03/23 10:35:48 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.assertions.BSFAssertion 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.extractor.BSFPostProcessor 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.BSFPreProcessor 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'keytool' 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file /Users/jordan/Downloads/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/proxyserver.jks 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.BSFSampler 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.config.MongoSourceElement 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.mongodb.sampler.MongoScriptSampler 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.timers.BSFTimer 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.BSFListener 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.MonitorHealthVisualizer 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2017/03/23 10:35:49 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
2017/03/23 10:38:54 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='/Users/jordan' 
2017/03/23 10:38:54 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: /Users/jordan/Downloads/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/test-plans/kafka-test.jmx 
2017/03/23 10:38:54 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='/Users/jordan/Downloads/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/test-plans' 
2017/03/23 10:38:54 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2017/03/23 10:38:54 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2017/03/23 10:38:54 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 3.1 
2017/03/23 10:38:54 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2017/03/23 10:38:54 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: /Users/jordan/Downloads/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/test-plans/kafka-test.jmx 
2017/03/23 10:38:54 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='/Users/jordan/Downloads/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/test-plans' 
2017/03/23 10:39:04 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2017/03/23 10:39:04 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2017/03/23 10:39:04 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2017/03/23 10:39:04 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler: Created class: co.signal.kafkameter.KafkaProducerSampler. Uses tearDownTest: true 
2017/03/23 10:39:04 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2017/03/23 10:39:05 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2017/03/23 10:39:05 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2017/03/23 10:39:05 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2017/03/23 10:39:05 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2017/03/23 10:39:05 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2017/03/23 10:39:05 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2017/03/23 10:39:05 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2017/03/23 10:39:05 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at kafka.utils.Logging$class.logger(Logging.scala:24)
    at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.logger(VerifiableProperties.scala:23)
    at kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.info(VerifiableProperties.scala:23)
    at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.verify(VerifiableProperties.scala:180)
    at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.scala:57)
    at co.signal.kafkameter.KafkaProducerSampler.setupTest(KafkaProducerSampler.java:90)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.sample(JavaSampler.java:193)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:475)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:418)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more

2017/03/23 10:39:05 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2017/03/23 10:39:05 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2017/03/23 10:39:05 WARN  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Error encountered during shutdown of org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler@51cd3642 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at co.signal.kafkameter.KafkaProducerSampler.teardownTest(KafkaProducerSampler.java:96)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.testEnded(JavaSampler.java:292)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:216)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:437)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2017/03/23 10:39:05 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

So, the error I get says that it cannot find `org/apache/log4j/logger`, but as I am not sure how to combat this problem. I have looked at [other known issues](https://github.com/BrightTag/kafkameter/issues) others have encountered to see if they were similar to mine, but to no avail. I thought perhaps I wrote my test plan wrong, but I can't find any issue with it. Is there any suggestion as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the complete stack trace ?

Comment: It is now, I just updated it from another run.

Comment: do you have log4j jar in your runtime ? if its a maven project add log4j as a dependency.

Comment: I'm going to assume that I don't. But right now, this is being tested on a dummy kafka setup I configured on my computer, it isn't being used for the project just yet.

Comment: Does this issue look similar to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054294/kafkaspout-throws-noclassdeffounderror-for-log4j

Comment: It does a little bit, but as I'm just trying to currently test it on a simple kafka configuration, I'm still a little confused as to where to put the log4j jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException This exception indicates that the
>   class was not found on the classpath. This indicates that we were
>   trying to load the class definition, and the class did not exist on
>   the classpath.

Try adding log4j jar.

If its a maven project you can add the below dependecy feel free to change to appropriate version.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

This might also happen if there is a version conflict as log4j jar might be present bundled within another jar try to find out and exclude the log4j jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Would I put the log4j jar in jMeter's lib/ext folder?

Comment: Marking your answer as accepted as you pointed me in the right direction. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. jMeter was missing the log4j jar, in its `lib` folder, when downloaded and put in said folder, the test runs without an issue.